# What does "invariant" mean? More precisely, invariant under a linear transformation?

Tags: functional-analysis

I have this exercise

> Show that the norm on $C[a,b]$ is invariant under a linear transformation $t = \alpha \tau +\beta$. Use this to prove the statement in example 3.1-8 by mapping $[a,b]$ onto $[0,1]$ and then considering the functions defined by $\tilde{x}(\tau)=1$, $\tilde{y}(\tau)= \tau$, where $\tau \in [0,1]$.

The example 3.1-8 is which the space $C[a,b]$ is not a Hilbert space. In the book, the author proved that the norm $|| x || = \max_{t \in J} |x(t)|$, with $J = [a,b]$ can not be obtained from an inner product. To prove this, let $x(t) = 1$ and $y(t) =\dfrac{t-a}{b-a}$, $t \in J$. With this, we can calculated $||x||, ||y||, ||x+y||$ and $||x-y||$ and show that the parallelogram identity is not valid 
$$
|| x + y||^2 + ||x-y||^2 = 2\left(||x||^2 + ||y||^2  \right).
$$ 
Now, with this exercise I got this solution:

---

The first part, we have
$$
a \leq t \leq b \iff a - \beta \leq t - \beta \leq b - \beta \iff \dfrac{a-\beta}{\alpha} \leq \dfrac{t-\beta}{\alpha} \leq \dfrac{b-\beta}{\alpha}.
$$
And to make $c = \dfrac{a-\beta}{\alpha}$, $\tau = \dfrac{t-\beta}{\alpha}$ and $d = \dfrac{b-\beta}{\alpha}$, we have
$$
a \leq t \leq b \iff c \leq \tau \leq d.
$$
Hence
$$
||\tilde{x}|| = \max_{\tau \in [c,d]}|\tilde{x}(\tau)| = \max_{\tau \in [c,d]}|x(\alpha \tau + \beta)| = \max_{t \in [a,b]}|x(t)| = ||x||.
$$

The second part, we defined $\tau = \dfrac{t-a}{b-a}$. This imples that $\tau \in [0,1]$ and $1 = x(t) = x(a + \tau(b-a)) = \tilde{x}(\tau)$ and $\tau = y(t) = y(a + \tau(b-a)) = \tilde{y}(\tau)$. This implies
$$
||\tilde{x}|| = 1, ||\tilde{y}|| = 1, ||\tilde{x}+\tilde{y}|| = 2\;\;\mbox{and}\;\; ||\tilde{x}-\tilde{y}|| = 1.
$$ 
This concludes the second part because $|| \tilde{x} + \tilde{y}||^2 + ||\tilde{x}-\tilde{y}||^2 =5\neq 4= 2\left(||\tilde{x}||^2 + ||\tilde{y}||^2  \right)$.

But I couldn't understand this solution. Maybe I don't know that does mean the object to be "invariant" another object.
Could someone explain the details, please? I know about the parallelogram equality and understand this (the statement why this is not a Hilbert Space).

Comment: It just means that if you apply a linear transformation to a continues function on $[a,b]$, the norm of the original function is the same as the norm of the transformed function.